# Trim whitespace in link with css

Tags: css

Is it possible to trim whitespaces with css? In the code snippet below there is a extra whitespace in the `<a>` tag. The link comes out of a wordpress plugin and I don't want to edit the plugin source files. The extra space is inside the source files. What I can do is apply css to the link.

```html
click <a href="#" class="foo">here </a>to login.
```

Worst case scenario I could use JavaScript. But that seems ugly to me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can also do something like this. Altough `display: inline-block` should be enough to remove the space.

```css
a.foo {
  width : 30px;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
click <a href="#" class="foo">here </a> to login.
```

Comment: you just need to be sure that the word "here" will never change and always take 30px whatever the user font-size preference or font-family

Comment: As this answer says, `display: inline-block` is all that's required. The fixed width is not needed and just adds confusion

Answer (score 4):

You could try playing with a negative `margin-right`, like so

```css
a.foo {
   display: inline-block;
   margin-right: -1em;
   padding-right: 1.25em;
}
```

```html
click <a href="#" class="foo">here </a>to login.
```

Comment: It works. But 1 more question. Chrome gives a warning when you inspect this. it says: invalid property value for the padding-right